# How to mount a Azure Blob in databricks notebook based on IF-condition?

Tags: python, sql, azure, databricks

Current working setup: I have one file in blob-storage, and in the current solution this file mounts in the notebook:

```
fileIn = '/mnt/myfile'
```

This file needs to be split into two files, separated by year. Now I have two files:

```
fileInA = '/mnt/myfile2015'
fileInB = '/mnt/myfile2022'
```

The current databricks Notebook take 'year' as inputparameter, eg:

```
# dbutils.widgets.text("year", "2019")
```

Based on input-year I need to spesify what file to mount.
First I tried by SQL:

```
> fileIn = SELECT if(year < 2022, 'fileInA', 'fileInB ');
```

but that returns the actual SQL statement as fileIn, and does not mount the file.

I alos tried with python:

```
def mountbyyear(year):
#   if(int(year)<2022):
#       fileIn = '/mnt/myfile2015'
#   else:
#       fileIn = '/mnt/myfile2022'
mountbyyear(year)
```

How can i mount a blob-file based on a IF-statement in Databricks Notebook?

Comment: What do you mean by this statement `This file needs to be separated by year, so now I have two files:`? And how are you mounting the file?

Comment: Instead of one file, i have two files, Its mounted as blob storage as indicated in the first section here: https://docs.databricks.com/_extras/notebooks/source/data-sources/mount-azure-blob-storage.html

Comment: How are you mounting these files?

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/_extras/notebooks/source/data-sources/mount-azure-blob-storage.html first section first section, wihtout extra confis part.

Comment: Can you provide the folder structure of the blob storage where these files are present?

Comment: Why is that relevant, it already mounts a file in the current solution. Now there are two files. Its not a problem with the storage

Comment: The link you have shared has information about mounting a container where as you are indicating mounting a file. Is it the containers that you are mounting?

Comment: Ok, i understand your question. It mounts a container where the file(s) resides ( I think). As far as i understand, it gets the file path from that mounted conatiner as variable. Then register that file as temporary table: sqlContext.read.parquet(fileIn).registerTempTable('tableName')

Comment: Is it not possible to "overwrite" variables in Databricks Notebooks ??

Comment: It is possible to change the value of a variable in Databricks notebooks. The mountbyyear() function should update the fileIn variable value. But how is this code not working? And what is mounting a file? Provide these details

Comment: "But how is this code not working?"  I dont know! I copied the function, and registerd temporary table based on IF-Statement with 2 different filenames instead, and that works! That means the function works. But with the variable way, the variable did  not change as far as i can see..... ?!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `global <variable_name>` in the function, to modify the variables which are outside of the function. If we don't use it, it will create new `fileIn` local variable inside the function instead of updating the existing variable.

Go through the below demonstration with and without `global` to understand better.

**Without `global`:**

[image]

**With `global`**:

[image]

Now, you can use the variable as per your requirement.